# Something wrong when delete group item automatically

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

I have a custom ExpandableListView and want to delete group item aotomatically if this group is empty. The problem is: when I delete the group after last child is deleted, the group below's child item will be doubled although getCount() return the correct number!

For example:

before delete:

```
g1={c1, c2}, g2={c3, c4}
```

after delete c1, c2:

```
g2={c3, c4, c3, c4}
```

the complete adapter code:

```
package base.util.ui.listview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;

public abstract class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = ExpandableListAdapter.class
            .getSimpleName();
    public List<IGroup> list;
    private Hashtable<String, Integer> table;

    public ExpandableListAdapter() {
        this(null);
    }

    public ExpandableListAdapter(IGroup[] groups) {
        list = new ArrayList<IGroup>();
        table = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; groups != null && i < groups.length; i++) {
            addGroup(groups[i]);
        }
    }

    public int addGroup(IGroup group) {
        list.add(group);
        table.put(group.getId(), list.indexOf(group));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return list.indexOf(group);
    }

    public void addChild(IGroup group, IChild child) {
        Integer position = table.get(group.getId());
        if (position == null) {
            position = addGroup(group);
        }

        if (position != -1) {
            getGroup(position).addChild(child);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void removeGroup(int groupPosition) {
        IGroup group = list.remove(groupPosition);
        table.remove(group.getId());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void removeChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        try {
            IGroup group = getGroup(groupPosition);
            group.removeChild(childPosition);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            if (group.getChildCount() == 0) {
                removeGroup(groupPosition);// !
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "removeChild(): " + getChildrenCount());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        list.clear();
        table.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getChildrenCount() {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getGroupCount(); i++) {
            result += getChildrenCount(i);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public IGroup getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return list.get(groupPosition);
    }

    public IChild getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return getGroup(groupPosition).getChild(childPosition);
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return -1;
        // return getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).childId;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return getGroup(groupPosition).getChildCount();
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public abstract View getGroupView(final int groupPosition,
            boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent);

    public abstract View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent);

    public void traverse(ITraverse task) {
        for (int g = getGroupCount() - 1; g >= 0; g--) {
            for (int c = getGroup(g).getChildCount() - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
                task.onTraverse(g, c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please notice that after I comment the removeGroup() from removeChild(), this problem never happend again. So anyone please tell me how to do it correctly? thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this, and it works:

```
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}
```